# How to optimize django Admin using queryset cache

Tags: django, admin

im trying to optimize dbase queries from the admin, by caching the results and using in coming queries. But - i still see dbase request for each entry.

i have a model like this:

```
class actions(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
   action = ...

class Myuser(Models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   company = models.ForeignKey(Companies)
```

in the admin change_list, i'd like to see a table with:

```
user    action    company_name
```

so i defined my admin as follows:

```
class ActionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('user','action','company_name')
  ...

 def company_name(self,instance):
   return instance.user.company
```

When i run this, i see that for each user, there is a query to the company model to extract the company's name. However, since there are not many companies and in many cases, users perform many actions once after the other, i want to query for all companies once and then use the cached result instead of accessing the dbase for each entry.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [list_select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) to specify the relation to select with the query, so in your case:

```
class ActionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('user','action','company_name')
  list_select_related = ('user__company', )
  ...

 def company_name(self,instance):
   return instance.user.company
```

Edit:

You can also specify the field directly on `list_display`, without the need for custom method.

It should handle `list_select_related` for you (at least according to the docs linked above). If assuming your `Companies` model has a `name` field:

```
class ActionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('user','action','user__company__name')
```